# logic to loop through records containing timestamps

Tags: php

I need help with some logic when handling timestamps.

I have a table with a few hundred records, each record has a field witch contains a timestamps.
I have `$NextAuditStamp`, this field is populated via a user input script which converts dates to timestamps.

Now I need to loop through each record and return all the records where the `$NextAuditStamp` minus `$n` is greater than `$NowTime`. Here is the test code I am currently work with to try and get the logic working:

```
$NowTime = time();

$Flag = "";

$n =  2635250; // this is a fixed timestamp representing 1 month

$NextAuditStamp = strtotime($_POST['NextAuditDate']);

if($NowTime - $n > $NextAuditStamp) {
    $Flag = 1;
} elseif($NowTime > $NextAuditStamp) {
    $Flag = 2;
} else {
    $Flag = "0";
}
```

Comment: why not do this in a query?

Comment: @nogad thanks for your reply, I am having enough trouble doing it this way. A query, I think would complicate it. Any thoughts on my question?

Comment: seems to work for me, whats the exact issue? what are the dates you are testing? `echo $NextAuditStamp;` check that is what you expect

Comment: What specifically about your logic isn't working as you'd expect? What type of times format are you passing through to `NextAuditDate`? If you're using **dates**, remember that `strtotime()` will only work with the **American** date format!

Comment: For testing, $NextAuditStamp is 1485907200 (timestamp) and $NowTime is 1509572053 (timestamp).

Comment: ^ returns flag 1, what did you expect?

Comment: Hi all, your completley right, I have been looking at this totally wrong. I am sorry for waisting your time. But you did make me look at it more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $NextAuditStamp minus $n is greater than $NowTime

Your test for `$Flag = 1` does the opposite, guess you want

```
if($NextAuditStamp - $n > $NowTime) {...}
```

Comment: Hi, thats exactly the change I made. But many thanks for looking at the question.